# setTimeout in restfull service

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, timer

I am writing service using **node.js + express**.  I have problems with **timer**.

I don't store any state at all, have 2 functions in my **route**.

**route.js**

```
var timeOutId;
exports.linkUpRequest = function() {
   // do some request to another user => insert record in db
   ...
   timeOutId = setTimeout(function() {
     //delete request => delete record from db
   }, 1000 * 60 * 60);
   res.send(...);
};


exports.confirm = function() {
   // record will be stored until user explicitly delete it => update that user confirm request
   clearTimeout(timeOutId);
   res.send(...);
};
```

I know that is is wrong solution because it is server and many user can access `timeOutId` variable. My question is how to deal with timer and timeout id in **REST** service.

Note: In comments I call methods from my models, which is also stateless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping track of all timer references is not going to be easy. One thing you can do is to store a confirmation status in db against each request. On confirmation, set status to confirmed. Check this status before deleting the record when timer ends, if confirmed do not delete the request. This way you wont be cancelling timers for confirmed requests but these requests do not get deleted on timeout.

Comment: Thank you. But if my server fail by some reason, I will have big problems, how make it fail safe? I mean my timer will be aborted. And my record doesn't delete.(sory for my english, I suppose you understand me)

Comment: You can schedule a script to run after x minutes to check if there are expired requests in your db which need to be deleted.